# Firebase deployment error

Tags: deployment, firebase, firebase-hosting

I've deployed in the past many times before. For some reason, today I am getting this error I can't seem to fix. I've tried changing tabs out with 2 or 4 spaces. I've tried different formats, and nothing works.

Here's what it says:

```
Error: There was an error loading firebase.json

Trailing comma in object at 29:9
    }
    ^
```

Here is my firebase.json

```
{
    "database": {
        "rules": "database.rules.json"
    },
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public"
    }
}
```

How do I solve it?

PS: If you need anything else please ask.

Comment: This is a stupid bug of their JSON parser: You actually do have an error in your JSON file, but the position it indicates is just plain wrong. As mentioned below, it is often caused by some trailing comma *somewhere* in your `rules.json` file (usually not even in the `firebase.json` file itself!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your firebase json file to

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
    ]
  }
}
```

If you are still having issues then you also have to change your database file to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up rewriting the database values to default even though they work in the actual firebase console. This ended up fixing my issue and I upload using this command: firebase deploy --except database

Answer (score 11):

To anyone experiencing this problem, I solved mine by going to the file "database.rules.json", and **removing the last comma** in the line `".write": true,`

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

It seems Firebase generated an invalid JSON.

Comment: Thanks I fixed this by removing the many trailing commas in the json which they downloaded from firebase... bit of an oversight from them! Especially the unhelpful error in the wrong file

Answer (score 6):

This error is caused by invalid JSON format within database.rules.json file.
First, open a database.rules.json file.
move to the end of line in the file.
**remove ',' at last position of the line.**

Answer (score 0):

This error means the JSON format of the **database.json** is invalid. Simply go to the line specified, 29 in your case, and remove the comma to make the JSON valid. JSON files do not allow trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `database.rules.json` has valid json format.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was showing this error in firebase.json file but I didn't find any error there and so I checked databaserules.json file and shown error was there. I corrected it and it worked.